# Detect specific point in animation clip loop [monster attack animation]

Tags: three.js

Im using AnimationMixer to play three AnimationClips for my monster: Idle, Walk and Attack.
When Monster attacks my player I want to deal the damage and do some stuff like reaction to the hit.
For this I need to detect exact time when Attack animation is at point when monster hand is stretched out and dealing the blow. I know the keyframe number in Blender, but is there a method to detect current frame using AnimationMixer and related classes?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the current frame in AnimationClip, but I was able to use animation time instead. I store my animation clip in variable when I create it:

```
currentAnimation = mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0])
currentAnimation.play();
```

and in animation loop where I advance the mixer I check the time:

```
mixer.update( delta );
if (currentAnimation.getClip().name == 'Attack' && currentAnimation.time > 1.5)
    showHit(true);
```

in my previous implementation I had attack_frame_number in monster json file, now it is called attack_time and it works ok.